# Arguing Developers Question

Tags: discussion

OK, so the question is, as far as it goes, fine, not great but not an immediate close (though maybe off-topic).

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/50989/arguing-developers

However, the answers have largely descended into a passive agressive self-help group with threats of violence and so on. There are enough up votes that simply down voting isn't going to do it - reason enough to close?

Or am I being OTT?

Comment: Was thinking the same thing.

Answer (score 11):

This question does not seem very specific to the profession of software development to me.

Really? Only programmers enter long, drawn out discussions yelling at each other?

I guess all those thousands of years of human history have steered me wrong, somehow!

Answer (score 4):

You can (and are encouraged to) vote to close if you feel that it's warranted. Adding a comment may also encourage others to consider voting similarly.

As far as the question goes, I agree that it's borderline, but I'd call it not constructive before calling it off-topic. Some of the answers are just attempts at humour, however potentially misguided. With a reasonable answer accepted, I think we can leave this as is for now (especially since it's now CW). If more unconstructive answers keep showing up, it may be worth protecting or locking the question.

Answer (score 3):

There's an Area 51 proposal for office-related issues that may be more appropriate for this sort of question (http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/22377/office-work-and-desk-jobs).

However, since that site is not yet launched, I think it is acceptable to leave the question on programmers.stackexchange.

Answer (score 2):

As the author of the accepted answer, I have to admit that I was very surprised, puzzled and at the same time slightly embarrassed at the number of votes it got. (Particularly when I compare it to the number of votes you get for a reasonably well-researched or insightful answer.)

While I don't think humour and irony should be banished from this site, life would be quite awful without them and we're all human (although some I suspect to be robots), it made me question the value of "how much the community trusts you".